# Como mostrar una variable del controlador en la vista thymeleaft

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Quisiera saber si es posible llamar una variable desde mi controlador a mi front ,algo asi :

```
<li th:if="${#lists.contains(campaigncontroller.rolesUsuFront, 'Support')}" class="nav-item with-sub">
```

Ya que necesito poner esa linea de codigo en todas mis vistas, este es el controlador que llamo:

```
public class CampaignController {

List<String> rolesUsuFront = new ArrayList<String>();
```